# RHEL 8 won't display icons with Gnome desktop extension active

Tags: rhel, gnome, desktop

I'm trying to get desktop icons to display in RHEL 8, and while I'm able to get the desktop entry files to display using Gnome Tweaks and enabling the desktop extension, none of the icons will display. I've confirmed that the image files exist where they're referred to in the desktop entry, and even with a minimal test .desktop file using a picture in my home directory I can't get it to display correctly.

Here's my test desktop entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Test
Exec=/bin/bash
Icon=/home/myUser/Desktop/testIcon.png
```

And here's how it looks in my desktop:

[image]

The desktop entry preview is rendered correctly in Nautilus:

[image]

The png file is something I made in GIMP to ensure it would be 64 × 64 px. Is there a way to get this to display correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured this out. There is a very particular set of conditions that have to be met for RHEL (not sure if this is specific to RHEL or GNOME) to display desktop icons correctly:

- The (.desktop) file must be executable
- The file must not contain any lines that are not recognized by gedit as correct desktop file syntax, e.g. my MATLAB.desktop contained `Path[$e]=` and the desktop icon only displays if this line is commented out. From the question linked below, here's the [GNOME desktop entry specification](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/).
- The file must contain the line `Type=Application`
- The file's Exec line must point to a single executable; my MATLAB.desktop contained `Exec=export an_environment_variable; /usr/local/MATLAB/R2020b/bin/matlab -desktop`, which worked in KDE but had to be changed to `Exec=sh -c "export...` in GNOME (credit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980464/how-do-i-access-an-environment-variable-in-a-desktop-files-exec-line) for helping me figure this one out)
- Finally, once every other requirement is met, you have to right click on the desktop icon and select "Allow Launching" in the context menu. Only then will the icon display correctly.